# CRT and Evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

Given the quotient ring $\displaystyle R = \frac{\mathbb{Z}_q[x]}{\langle P(x)\rangle}$, for a prime $q$ and an irreducible polynomial $P(x)\in \mathbb{Z} [x]$. my question is there exist  a $P,q$ and  elements $w,\gamma$ from $\mathbb{Z}_q$ so we have $\forall a\in R$: $a(w) = w a(\gamma)$.

I tried to show it using cyclic extensions (choosing $P$ such that the number field $K$ defined by $P$ is cyclic) and by Kummer-Dedekind theorem we choose an totally unramified $q$ ($e=f=1$ and $g=\deg(P)$) in $K$  but I got stuck at the existence/inexistence of such a  $w$

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: I tried to show it using cyclic extensions (choosing $P$ such that the number field $K$ defined by $P$ is cyclic) and by Kummer-Dedekind  theorem we choose an totally unramified $q$ $ (e=f=1\text{ and }g = \deg(P))$ in  but I got stuck at the existence of such a $w$.

Comment: You have 100 times more knowledge in math than I do. I don’t understand what you have written. I saw your post in review queue,  read post and it seems like it only contain question. In math SE, you should show your progress (partial and/or ful) and your thoughts. That’s the general rule of this site. You can copy paste above comment to your post.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`

Comment: I think it is not necessary to have $a(w)=aw(1)$ we can change this by : is there exist $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_q$  such that $a(w) = a w(\gamma)$ for every $w\in \mathbb{Z}_q$.